# how to search txt in a file not a character

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp1;
   fp1 = fopen("math.dat", "r");
   char ch;
   int i=0;

 while (1) {
      ch = fgetc(fp1);                       
      if (ch == '3')
          i++;
      if (ch == EOF)
          break;
}

   printf("there is : %d matches\n", i);

   return(0);
}
```

This code is only for searching number "3" in the txt file called math.dat.  I would like to search more than one character. Can anyone help?

Comment: use `fgets` to read strings and then search.

Comment: Also: `char ch;` --> `int ch;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `strchr()` to search for each input character in a string:

```
const char *search_group = "34ab";
...
if (strchr(search_group, ch))
```

`strchr()` returns NULL if the character isn't found, or a pointer to
the first match.

Edit suggested by chux's comment: if you don't want `'\0'` to be considered
a part of the search group, use `memchr` instead.

Comment: 1) D'oh! Thanks. 2) It will? Why?

Comment: Because  `"34ab"` has 5 `char` in it and `ch == 0` matches one of them. "The strchr function locates the first occurrence of c (converted to a char) in the string pointed to by s. The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string."

Comment: That wouldn't stop the program. It would simply count the `'\0'` character. Perhaps not the expected behavior, but it wouldn't stop.

Comment: 1) Did not suggest code would stop.  But if the source file had the unlikely null character in it, incorrect results would occur.  2) Yes, `memchr()` is a superior solution.

Comment: "Note: code will **stop** the first time ch == '\0'."

Comment: Agreed, my initial comment should have been " 
Note: code will match when `ch == '\0'".

Comment: Oh, *that* kind of stop :)

Comment: it seems, strchr function is still looking for single characters, I wanted to search a number for instance 34, it searches number 3, and number 4. Or am i doing it in a wrong way?

Comment: For that you need to use `strstr()` or such. `man strstr` or google it.